# How to tab-complete in terminal while stay on the same line?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

When double-tab, the terminal shows a list of command candidates, but the cursor line also moves downwards. How to make it stay on the same line while showing all the candidates below?

I'm guessing there must be some config file that can specify this behavior. This also applies to the case when ctrl-c in the middle of typing a command. I'd like the cursor to stay on the current line.

Comment: Like when you quit vi/m (`:q`) it exists but stays on the same line (making the whole window still visible)?

Comment: Z shell does/can do that, but I'm not aware of any way to get Bash to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need shell with rich terminal support.

For example **Z Shell**. **Bash** build with **readline** library for user interaction and it operate only line-by-line...

This behavior allow to run Bash on most platform as does not require special abilities from terminal.